# Adding Items to a ComboBox created in FXML (inside the Controller class of a JavaFX Application)

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml

I am using a FXML file to get the GUI part of my application done. Inside some H and V-Boxes I got this:

```
<ComboBox id="comboBoxLearn" fx:id="comboBoxLearn" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="300.0" promptText="Choose List..." style="-fx-font-size: 24;"/>
```

On the other hand, I got a Controller.java class in which I got this (and some more irrelevant code):

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> comboBoxLearn;

/**
 * Initialize
 */
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    comboBoxLearn = new ComboBox<>();
    comboBoxLearn.getItems().setAll("General", "Test", "Test2");
    comboBoxLearn.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}
```

What I want is:
- initializing the comboBoxLearn with the 3 values "General", "Test", "Test2" and set "General" as default value.

It doesn't work right now. No exception or error but the box is just blank.

EDIT:
Leaving out the line

```
comboBoxLearn = new ComboBox<>();
```

doesn't help either but then an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your `ComboBox` and choose a selected value value like this:

```
<ComboBox id="comboBoxLearn" fx:id="comboBoxLearn">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="General"/>
            <String fx:value="Test"/>
            <String fx:value="Test2"/>
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
    <value>
        <String fx:value="General"/>
    </value>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you create new Combobox object. If you annotate Combobox with @FXML you cannot create new object because Java do that basing on your fxml file where you specified your combobox.

**EDIT**

Ater remove creation of new object there was exception caused by main class because it doesn't apply controller class to view files. Controller doesn't have a zero-argument constructor. When fx:controller was added to .fxml file it tries to create instance of that controller which doesn't have zero-argument constructor and program throws exception. Removing fx:controller from fxml file and added below code solved the problem

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
loader.setController(new MainController(path));
Pane mainPane = loader.load();
```